# Why do some trees flower year round, others only once

Tags: ecology, flowering

[image]Depending on latitude, rains, and pollinator behavior, etc. some trees flower only once a year such as oak trees, others twice (such as pipe organ cati as a response to pollinating bats) and yet others continously such as figs (I believe, not sure).

However I noticed that arbutus unedo (straberry tree) has both immature flowers, mature flowers young fruit and ripe fruit on the tree at the same time. To mky knowlesge, fig tress in amazonia behave differently: the whole tree is roughly in the same state at once, either "flowering" developing fruit, bearing ripe fruit.

My question is what ecological role does Arbutus U. fill that it has this feature?